# Is bind in javascript supposed to be used in a non-global context , if so what is wrong with the below code?

Tags: javascript, global, bind

```js
let info = {
  name: "Mark",
  age: 23,
  location: function(cname) {
    console.log("Hello " + this.name + " you are " + this.age + " years old and you live in " + cname)
  }
};


let details = info.location.bind(info, "mumbai");
console.log(details);
```

What is wrong with the code ?
I have used the bind method over here, I did validate the syntax before.

Comment: `.bind` returns a *function* - you still have to execute it. If you just want to call a function with a different `this`, then use `.call` or `.apply`

Comment: Why are you trying to use bind here?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? The below code would give you "Hello Mark you are 23 years old and you live in mumbai" in the console which I believe you are trying.

```
 let info = {
  name : "Mark",
  age : 23 , 
  location : function city(cname){
  console.log("Hello "+this.name+ " you are "+ this.age+ " years old and you live in " + cname )
}
};

info.location("mumbai")
```

If you call location as a method of the object info, its "this" will automatically be set to the object info. So you do not need bind. You would need bind if you call it like below:

```
const myFun = info.location;
myFun = myFun.bind(info);
myFun("mumbai");
```

Comment: I am trying to learn the bind method. So I have to use it.

Comment: @GeoMukkath `console.log(details)` -> `details()` simply execute the function you get. And there is no need for `console.log` - it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need bind, if you call the function on your object it will display the desired result, however if you call it on the global context then the this.props will be undefined.

It all depends how you call your function, on the custom object scope or on the global window object scope, depending on that, the this reference will defer.

```js
let info = {
  name: "Mark",
  age: 23,
  location: function(cname) {
    console.log("Hello " + this.name + " you are " + this.age + " years old and you live in " + cname)
  }
};

// displays undefined this refers to window object
const globalFunc = info.location
globalFunc('mumbai')

// calling funciton on global scope with passing info object as an argument
globalFunc.call(info,'mumbai')


info.location('mumbai')
```